# Is tokenize($s) the same as tokenize($s, ' ')?

Tags: xslt-3.0, xquery-3.1, xpath-3.1

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize explains about the single argument version of `tokenize`:

> The one-argument form of this function splits the supplied string at
>   whitespace boundaries.

and then goes on to define or explain that with

> calling `fn:tokenize($input)` is equivalent to calling
>   `fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space($input), ' '))` where the second
>   argument is a single space character (x20)

However, when I try `count(tokenize('1 2 3')), count(tokenize('1&#10;2&#10;3'))` with Saxon or BaseX or XmlPrime I get `3 3` while the supposedly equivalent `count(tokenize('1 2 3', ' ')), count(tokenize('1&#10;2&#10;3', ' '))` in all three implementations gives me `3 1`.

So all three implementations seem to do with `tokenize($s)` what the textual explanation says ("splits the supplied string at whitespace boundaries") but it doesn't seem that the equivalence of `fn:tokenize($input)` and `fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space($input), ' '))` given in the spec holds up, if a space is literally passed in then only that single space is used as a separator and not whitespace boundaries.

Is that equivalence given in the spec as a definition of the single argument version wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call on `normalize-space()` replaces newlines by x20 space characters. So while `count(tokenize('1&#10;2&#10;3', ' '))` gives 1, `count(tokenize(normalize-space('1&#10;2&#10;3'), ' '))` gives 3.

The substitution of newlines and tabs by single spaces could have been achieved using a smarter regular expression, but the key thing that the call on `normalize-space()` achieves is to trim leading and trailing whitespace. For example `tokenize(" red green blue ", "\s+")` gives 5 tokens, but `tokenize(" red green blue ")` gives 3.